# What Twitter #hashtags apply to IT Security

Tags: research, user-education

I'm trying to search twitter for evidence of near-realtime alerts or updates regarding security issues.

What hashtags are common or popular in the IT Security world?

Comment: Related: [What security resources should a white hat developer follow these days](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/571/396)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#infosec and #security are the two main hashtags I'm aware of.

Depending on what you're interested in there are other less popular hashtags. For example:

- #websecurity
- #privacy
- #cybercrime
- #cyberwar
- #hacker and #hackers
- #cybersecurity
- #malware
- #spam

There's also the option to use multiple hashtags in your search. If, for example, you are interested in Android security, you can search for "[#android AND #security](https://twitter.com/#!/search/#android%20AND%20#security)".

Answer (score 3):

It all depends on the type of content your are posting. In most cases you will need more than one #Tag for your tweet to make the right sense and ranking.

- #InfoSec (preferred abbreviation)
- #InformationSecurity (if you have some characters left in your tweet)
- #Risk (Topics also relating to risk management)
- #Privacy
- #Malware
- #Virus
- #Spam
- #BYOD
- #DataTheft / #DataLoss / #DataLeak
- #CISO / #CSO (If your tweet needs to draw attention of senior management audience)
- #Breach (If you are referring to a compromise)
- #Hack / #Hacker (You may use these along with #Breach)
- #MobileSec / #MobileSecurity

I'm an information security professional & often post on Twitter.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the following:

- #mobilemalware
- #mobilesecurity
- #informationsecurity

Comment: I would personally go with #infosec instead, much shorter (stupid twitter character limit) and everyone in the industry knows it.

Comment: Well, this is the most advisable method no matter what. However, the others are also useful for specifications and not everyone (unfortunately) is aware of the #infosec hashtag.

Answer (score 0):

I've done a quite of research & since security industry is a vast sphere, here are complete elements of hashtags which I found useful, you can go through these.

```
infosec
security
threat
security assessment
pentest
penetration test
vulnerability
vulnerability assessment
cybersec
cyber security
cyber
malware
ransomware
spyware
webappsec
netsec
network security
infrasec
infrastructure security
wireless security
wpa security
appsec
mobile security
ios security
android security
cyber forensics
vapt
va/pt
oscp
cissp
ceh
router security
api security
rest security
hack
hacker
hactivists
hacking
ethical hacking
wordpress security
drupal security
magento security
threat modeling
threat analyst
security analyst
siem
soc
security operations
information security
security operation
cybersec
offsec
perimeter security
reverse engineering
source code audit
security audit
source code review security
dast
sast
dynamic security
runtime security
static security
code security
wapt
data security
dlp
data leakage
osint
business logic security
bugbounty
bugsbounty
```

Feel free to add more of these & return to the community.

Thanks, do well.